# Can one mix data types in CNTK ElementSelect?

Tags: c#, cntk

I'm trying to do the following in CNTK (in C#):

```
a = ElementSelect(x, y, z);
```

expecting something equivalent to `a[i] = (x[i] != 0 ? y[i] : z[i])`.  However, for various reasons, `x` is `Int8` whereas `y` and `z` are of type `Double`.  CNTK is throwing an exception:

```
Primitive op 'Select' passed operands 'Output('Block34_Output_0', [?], [*, #]), Output('Plus47_Output_0', [?], [*, #]), Constant('Constant5', [], [])' 
with different DataTypes 'Int8' and 'Double'.
```

This is true, but I'm slightly surprised there is a "same type" constraint between the predicate `x` and the values `y` and `z`.

Is there a way around this?  Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For cntk's python api (v2.6), the following works:

```
a = C.input_variable(5)
b = C.input_variable(5)

c = C.element_select(a, b, b)

n = np.random.random((3, 5)).astype(int)
m = np.random.random((3, 5)).astype(np.float32)


print(c.eval({a: n, b: m}))
```

If C# doesn't allow it then i suggest you convert your int into float.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: I tried it, then got the error message "Only float or double is supported by CNTK.".  Rats.